# pythonを使用して複数のcsvデータを操作

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

pythonを使用して２つのcsvファイルを一つにまとめたいと考えております。

【list1】
route_node,X,Y
50775,-7882.7599,-43837.4058
50774,-7886.58284,-43851.12686
50772,-7895.8552,-43835.9677

【list2】
id,x,y
57136,-10171.54496,-44468.08496
31001,-10798.00999,-47051.58

上記のように【list1】と【list2】があった時に
listを一つにまとめ、

【new_list】
route_node,X,Y,id,x,y
50775,-7882.7599,-43837.4058,57136,-10171.54496,-44468.08496
50775,-7882.7599,-43837.4058,31001,-10798.00999,-47051.58
50774,-7886.58284,-43851.12686,57136,-10171.54496,-44468.08496
50774,-7886.58284,-43851.12686,31001,-10798.00999,-47051.58
・
・
・
といったように【list1】のすべてのidに対して【list2】のすべてのroute_nodeを合わせるには
どのような関数を使えばよろしいのでしょうか。
"merge"を使おうかと思ったのですが、"merge"は２つのデータに共通の値がある時に使用するという認識であり、今回の場合には"merge"は使用できないのではないかと思っております。

初歩的な内容で申し訳ございませんが、ご教授いただけましたら幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

一時的に「データに共通の値」(以下では `key` カラム)を作成して、outer join します。

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df1 = pd.read_csv('list1.csv')
>>> df2 = pd.read_csv('list2.csv') 
>>> df1.assign(key=0).merge(df2.assign(key=0), how='outer').\
    drop(columns='key').to_csv('new_list.csv', index=False)

$ cat new_list.csv
route_node,X,Y,id,x,y
50775,-7882.7599,-43837.4058,57136,-10171.54496,-44468.08496
50775,-7882.7599,-43837.4058,31001,-10798.00999,-47051.58
50774,-7886.582840000001,-43851.126860000004,57136,-10171.54496,-44468.08496
50774,-7886.582840000001,-43851.126860000004,31001,-10798.00999,-47051.58
50772,-7895.8552,-43835.9677,57136,-10171.54496,-44468.08496
50772,-7895.8552,-43835.9677,31001,-10798.00999,-47051.58
```

Comment: "merge"はこういった場合にも使用可能なのですね。
上記を実行するとdrop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'
といったエラーが出てしまうのですがどう修正すればよいのでしょうか。

Comment: こちらで利用している pandas のバージョンは `0.24.2` ですが、それよりの以前のバージョンをお使いでしょうか？ 一応、`drop('key', axis=1)` に書き換えて試してみていただけますか。

Answer (score 1):

主な処理をこの`itertools.product()`で出来そうです。
[Pythonで複数のリストの直積（デカルト積）を生成するitertools.product](https://note.nkmk.me/python-itertools-product/)
[itertools.product - return list instead of tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22883348/9014308)

入出力は`csv`なんで面倒ですが。それとこの辺のリスト処理を使って。
[5.1. リスト型についてもう少し](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)
[Python 3 で flatten する方法いろいろ](https://qiita.com/hoto17296/items/e1f80fef8536a0e5e7db)

```
import csv
import itertools

list1 = []
with open('list1.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        list1.append(row)

list2 = []
with open('list2.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        list2.append(row)

header = list1.pop(0)
header.extend(list2.pop(0))

list3 = [sum(list(tup), []) for tup in itertools.product(list1, list2)]
list3.insert(0, header)

with open('list3.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(list3)
```